# How to generate 3 unique random numbers excluding a particular no. in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to generate 3 non-repeating random numbers excluding a particular no.? For example:

```
n = 1;
a = ?;
b = ?;
c = ?;
where a!=b && a!=c && a!=n &&b!= a && b!=c &&b!=n &&c!=a &&c!=b &&c!=n;
```

another example would be

nextInt is 5 and n is 1 then I want to display 2,3,4 and 3,4,5, and 2,3,5 whenever the method gets called.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want 3 random numbers, or do you want 3 Lists each containing 3 numbers? Btw you have duplicate conditional checks in your last line.

Comment: I want 3 random numbers. no lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for instance utilize the [`Set<E>`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Set-class.html) class. When you create a new random number, check if it's valid (ie different from `n`). If yes add to the set. Do this until the set contains enough (ie `3`) elements.

```
import "dart:math";

void main() {
  int randomCount = 3; 
  int avoid = 15;
  var randomNumbers = new Set<int>();
  var rand = new Random();
  
  while (randomNumbers.length != randomCount) {
    int r = rand.nextInt(100);
    if (r != avoid)
      randomNumbers.add(r);
  }
  
  randomNumbers.forEach((element) => print(element));
}
```

Comment: wow thanks it worked. you algo master. help me in finding the yellow stone. xD